# Is $ \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{n \in N} a_n x^n$ a norm on the space of sequences $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The set of sequences of <del>integers</del> real numbers $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is not a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)  but it is a <del>[Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space)</del> vector space.  However, it can be a Hilbert space if I give it a norm such as :

$$ \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{n \in N} |a_n|^2 $$

and require that the norm be less than infinity.  What happens if I use a different equation.

$$ \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{n \in N} a_n x^n$$

Could this constitute a norm on the Banach space of sequence of integers (I forget the name in the textbook).  Maybe we need to say $0 < x < 1$ and / or put absolute value signs.

"Norm" on an infinite dimensional space means we have to strict to convergent subsequences (or we could accept the case $||v|| = \infty$ as an outcome.  The vector $\vec{1} = (1,1,1,\dots)$ is has infinite norm in the first case.

---

In terms of [sequences spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) the norm I have written is $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.  Certainly there is an $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$, even though it can [diverge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) for many sequences.

$$ \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{n \in N} |a_n| $$

Then I am asking about a weighted version of $\ell^1$.  with $0 < x < 1$.  Is that still a norm?

$$\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq\left\{  \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} :  \sum_{n \in N} |a_n| x^n < \infty \right\} $$

I believe the left side is strictly smaller than the right side.  There could also be an analogue of $\ell^2$:

$$\ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq\left\{  \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} :  \sum_{n \in N} |a_n|^2 x^n < \infty \right\} $$

Comment: The space of _all_ sequences is a Banach space? That's news to me - what norm are you referring to?

Comment: First, the sequences are **real** ones, not "integer ones" . Second, you cannot "require" the norm to be such that that series converges: there're lots of real sequence which are not summable, so either you restrict seriously your future-to-be space to sequences which are summable, or you change the definition of your  "norm" (which is not such)...or something else.

Comment: @DonAntonio Come on - it seems clear that when he talks about "requiring" a norm to be finite what he means is restricting the domain...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Common...is it really? From what I read I have the feeling the OP isn't sure what is going here almost at all. Calling the elements of that set "sequence of integers" at least twice is a strong hint for me. And thus for me it isn't clear at all what he really means...

Comment: Regarding whether that wieghted $\ell^1$ norm is actually a norm (on the space of sequences for which it's finite): have you tried to check this from the definition? What part seems hard?

Comment: If you insist on $a_n$ being _integers_, this is not even a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a norm of such sort on the vector space of all real sequences, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, as your sums don't have to converge.

However, some of the constructions you propose are indeed vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Let's show it for any $p \in [1, +\infty\rangle$.

Fix $x \in \langle 0, 1\rangle$ and define:

$$\ell_{x,p} = \left\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} : \sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^px^n < +\infty\right\}$$

$\ell_{x,p}$ is indeed a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$:

For $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty, (b_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_{x,p}$ we have:

$$|a_n + b_n|^p \le (|a_n| + |b_n|)^p \le \big(2\max\big\{|a_n|, |b_n|\big\}\big)^p = 2^p \max\big\{|a_n|^p, |b_n|^p\big\} \le 2^p (|a_n|^p + |b_n|^p)$$
so we get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n + b_n|^px^n \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty2^p(|a_n|^p + |b_n|^p)x^n = 2^p\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^px^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n|^px^n\right) < +\infty$$

We conclude $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty + (b_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_{x,p}$.

For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_{x,p}$ we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\lambda a_n|^px^n = |\lambda|^p\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^px^n < +\infty$$

Hence $\lambda(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_{x,p}$.

Since $\ell_{x,p}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, we conclude that $\ell_{x,p} \le \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Your observation that $\ell^p(\mathbb{N}) \subseteq \ell_{x,p}$ is correct. Take $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$. We have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p\underbrace{x^n}_{\le1} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p < +\infty$$

so $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^{x,p}$.

---

Futhermore, we can turn $\ell_{x, p}$ into a normed space in the way you suggested.

Define $\|\cdot\|_{x,p} : \ell_{x, p} \to \mathbb{R}$ as:

$$\left\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^px^n}, \text{ for } (a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_{x,p}$$

To show that $\|\cdot\|_{x,p}$ is a norm on $\ell_{x, p}$, it is useful to notice that for $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_{x,p}$ we have $\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ and:

$$\left\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} = \left\|\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_p$$

where $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the standard $p$-norm on $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$.

Indeed, $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{x,p} \ge 0$.

We have $\left\|0\right\|_{x,p} = 0$. Assume $0 = \left\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} = \left\|\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_p$. It follows that $\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty = 0$ so $a_n = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have:

$$\left\|\lambda (a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} = \left\|(\lambda a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} = \left\|\left(\lambda a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_p = |\lambda| \left\|\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_p = |\lambda| \left\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p}$$

Finally, for the triangle inequality we have:

\begin{align}
\left\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty + (b_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} &=\left\|(a_n + b_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p}\\
&= \left\|\left((a_n + b_n)x^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{p}\\
&= \left\|\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty + \left(b_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{p}\\
&\le \left\|\left(a_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{p} + \left\|\left(b_nx^{\frac{n}p}\right)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{p}\\
&= \left\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p} + \left\|(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty\right\|_{x,p}
\end{align}

Hence, $\|\cdot\|_{x,p}$ is a norm and $\left(\ell_{x,p}, \|\cdot\|_{x,p}\right)$ is a normed space.